# List tables names in spark database - sparklyR

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

Is there a way to list all the tables within a database?

Something like `src_databases(sc)` but for the objects inside a particular database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a SQL query retuns the desired information:

`dbGetQuery(sc, "SHOW TABLES IN db_schema")`

Answer (score 5):

You can also use

`dplyr::src_tbls(sc)`

To see the list of tables in the current active database with `sparklyr`.